# Preciso percorrer os dados de vários txt, pegar dados especificos e gerar um csv

Tags: php, regex, csv, txt, sistema-de-arquivos

Já estou percorrendo os arquivos e acessando os dados, mas preciso pegar o que está depois da seguinte linha:

P.A.C.(*) inicial P.A.C. (*) Sopave da cota devida 3a. parcela contemplação devidas devidas pago efetivados Saldo Sopave

até a linha a cima deste dados:
(*) Proposta de Admissão em Consórcio

Estou pensando em fazer com regex ou usar um if...

Este é meu código:

```
<?php

//PERCORRENDO OS ARQUIVOS TXT DO LIVRO 02
$path = "/guardiao/files/juridico/Livro 02 - Medio - Ok";
$diretorio = dir($path);
echo '<pre>';
while($arquivo = $diretorio -> read()){
if ($arquivo == '.' || $arquivo == '..') continue;
$ext = array_reverse(explode(".", $arquivo))[0];

if($ext == 'txt'){
    //echo $arquivo.'<br/>';
    $conteudo = file_get_contents($path.'/'.$arquivo);
    //SUBSTITUIR ESPEÇO EM BRANCO POR ;
    $subst_espaço = preg_replace("/( )+/", ';', $conteudo);
    //TRANSFORMAR CADA LINHA EM UM ARRAY
    $linhas = explode("\n", $subst_espaço);
    foreach ($linhas as $linha) {
         echo $linha;
        $linha_dados = 1;
        $linha_titulo = 'a';
        if ($linha) {

        }
    }
    // $linhas = count($ler);
    //PEGAR SOMENTE OS DADOS APÓS A LINHA QUE POSSUIR ; E UM NUMERO
    // var_dump($ler);
     //print_r($linha);
    // exit();

}
// print_r($ext.'<br/>');
// echo $arquivo."<br />";
}
$diretorio -> close();

?>
```

> Este é um dos arquivos:

e

&

Anexo VI

Rodobens Administração e Promoções Ltda.

Comissões sobre vendas de cotas de consórcio - Imóveis
Data-base: 22 de maio de 2002

Em reais
% de

% de comissão _ comissão Comissão Comissão Comissão Estorno de Total de Saldo
Numero Crédito _ devida conforme planilha - Status inicial devida na devida na comissões comissões Valor __ Estornos planilha
P.A.C.(*) inicial P.A.C. (*) Sopave da cota devida 3a. parcela contemplação devidas devidas pago efetivados Saldo Sopave
150.620 25.000,00 2,62% 1,42% Ativo 655,00 125,00 0,00 0,00 780,00 655,00 0,00 125,00 (300,00)
150.619 25.000,00 2,62% 1,42% Ativo 655,00 125,00 0,00 0,00 780,00 655,00 0,00 125,00 (300,00)
150.610 25.000,00 2,62% 1,42% Ativo 655,00 125,00 0,00 0,00 780,00 780,00 0,00 0,00 355,00
150.607 80.000,00 2,62% 1,42% Ativo 2.096,00 400,00 0,00 0,00 2.496,00 2.496,00 0,00 0,00 1.136,00
150.605 25.000,00 2,62% 1,42% Ativo 655,00 125,00 0,00 0,00 780,00 780,00 0,00 0,00 355,00
150.560 30.000,00 2,62% 1,42% Inativo 786,00 0,00 0,00 336,00 450,00 450,00 0,00 0,00 426,00
150.556 80.000,00 0,00% 1,42% Inativo 0,00 0,00 0,00 0,00 0,00 0,00 0,00 0,00 1.136,00
150.533 25.000,00 2,62% 1,42% Inativo 655,00 0,00 0,00 655,00 0,00 0,00 0,00 0.00 355,00
150.531 25.000,00 2,62% 1,42% Inativo 655,00 0,00 0,00 655,00 0,00 0,00 0,00 0,00 355,00
150.522 30.000,00 2,62% 1,42% Ativo 786,00 150,00 0,00 0,00 936,00 936,00 0,00 0,00 426,00
150.493 50.000,00 2,62% 1,42% Ativo 1.310,00 250,00 0,00 0,00 1.560,00 1.560,00 0,00 0,00 710,00
150.443 25.000,00 2,62% 1,42% Ativo 655,00 125,00 0,00 0,00 780,00 780,00 0,00 0,00 355,00
150.439 25.000,00 2,62% 1,42% Ativo 655,00 125,00 0,00 0,00 780,00 780,00 0,00 0,00 355,00
150.432 35.000,00 2,62% 1,42% Ativo 917,00 175,00 0,00 0,00 1.092,00 1.092,00 0.00 0,00 497,00
150.426 25.000,00 2,62% 3,12% Ativo 655,00 125,00 125,00 0,00 905,00 0,00 0,00 905,00 (125,00)
150.420 25.000,00 2,62% 2,62% Ativo 655,00 125,00 0,00 0,00 780,00 780,00 0,00 0,00 655,00
150.404 25.000,00 2,62% 1,42% Inativo 655,00 0,00 0,00 280,00 375,00 655,00 0,00 (280,00) (300,00)
150.403 25.000,00 2,62% 1,42% Inativo 655,00 0,00 0,00 280,00 375,00 655,00 0,00 (280.00) (300,00)
150.401 55.000,00 2,62% 1,42% Inativo 1.441,00 0,00 0,00 616,00 825,00 825,00 0,00 0,00 (660.00)
150.400 25.000,00 2,62% 1,42% Inativo 655,00 0,00 0,00 280,00 375,00 655,00 0,00 (280,00) (300.00)
150.397 25.000,00 2,62% 1,42% Inativo 655,00 0,00 0,00 280,00 375,00 655,00 0,00 (280,00) (200,00)
150.394 25.000,00 2,62% 1,42% Inativo 655,00 0,00 0,00 280,00 375,00 655,00 0,00 (280,06) (200,00)
150.392 25.000,00 2,62% 1,42% Inativo 655,00 0,00 0,00 280,00 375,00 655,00 0,00 (280,00) (300,00)
150.391 25.000,00 2,62% 1,42% Inativo 655,00 0,00 0,00 280,00 375,00 655,00 0,00 (280.00) (300,00)
150.388 25.000,00 2,62% 1,42% Inativo 655,00 0,00 0,00 280,00 375,00 655,00 0,00 (280.00) (300,00)
(*) Proposta de Admissão em Consórcio
(**) PAC constante no relatório de reposição de setembro de 2001 1?

Answer (score 2):

> [...] preciso pegar o que está depois da seguinte linha:
>
> P.A.C.() inicial P.A.C. () Sopave da cota devida 3a. parcela
> contemplação devidas devidas pago efetivados Saldo Sopave
>
> [...] até a linha a cima deste dados: (*) Proposta de Admissão em Consórcio

Já que você já determinou um ponto de início e de fim estático, é só colocar esses pontos entre o grupo de captura com o token `.` que captura qualquer caractere e um quantificador `*?` *lazy*, ele irá capturar todos os caracteres até a primeira ocorrência da sequencia `(*) Proposta de Admissão em Consórcio`.

Então use essa regex para capturar o conteúdo que você deseja:

```
P\.A\.C\.\(\) inicial P\.A\.C\. \(\) Sopave da cota devida 3a\. parcela contemplação devidas devidas pago efetivados Saldo Sopave(.*?)\(\*\) Proposta de Admissão em Consórcio
```

Com ela você pode usar o comando `preg_match_all()` e `preg_match()`, depois disso é só você colocar o resultado em uma variável e escreve-la em um csv como você mencionou no título.

[Você pode ver um exemplo da regex funcionando aqui.](https://regex101.com/r/OolveD/1/)

---

Exemplo [preg_match()](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-php.html#match):

```
$subject = 'seu texto aqui';
$pattern='~P\.A\.C\.\(\) inicial P\.A\.C\. \(\) Sopave da cota devida 3a\. parcela contemplação devidas devidas pago efetivados Saldo Sopave(.*?)\(\*\) Proposta de Admissão em Consórcio~';
$success = preg_match($pattern, $subject, $match);
if ($success) {
    echo "Match: ".$match[1]."<br />";
}
```

Exemplo [preg_match_all()](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-php.html#matchall):

```
$subject = 'seu texto aqui';
$pattern='~P\.A\.C\.\(\) inicial P\.A\.C\. \(\) Sopave da cota devida 3a\. parcela contemplação devidas devidas pago efetivados Saldo Sopave(.*?)\(\*\) Proposta de Admissão em Consórcio~';
$hits = preg_match_all($regex,$airports,$matches,PREG_SET_ORDER); //hits é o vetor com seus matches
```